# Call External Javascript function using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need to call a javascript function from my controller in codeigniter.It is possible in codeigniter ?
Problem Details
My javascript file contains

```
function debugOutput(msg) {
 alert (msg);
}
```

and also I need to call it from my controller.

I done it as follows.

```
<?php
function check()
{
header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');
// body here
}
?>
function execute() {
    debugOutput("&lt;?php echo 'test'; ?&gt;");
}
execute();
```

But it is not working.Please help me to solve it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what do you want to do here. Also formatting your code a little would help a lot for readability and understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.Here I am sharing that answer;

```
<?php function check(){
{header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');?>
        function execute() {
        showName(<?php echo 'ajithperuva';?>);
        }
        execute();
    <?php
    }
```

This script will invoke an external javascript function showName().
Thanks for all help me in my trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you would need to surround the call with `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function execute() {
 ...
 }
</script>
```